# Strange powerplane layering issue in designspark

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

I'm trying to order a 6 layer PCB from a fab but they are asking me to resolve an issue with the file and I'm a bit stumped on what to do about it.

The second layer of the design I have designated as a power plane but I am also running a couple of short traces through it.

[image: Power plane]

The problem is, when I output the gerber files of the PCB I get both a positive and a negative plot of the same plane.
In gerberviewer it looks like this with the negative plot
[image: Negative]

and this with the positive plot added
[image: positive]

It seems to me that the positive plot is adding the copper trace to the power plane and the negative plot is adding the cutout around the trace, which means they are both neccesary, but you can't have a positive and a negative plot for the same plane.
What am I supposed to do here? Mistakes would be costly for me.